# How can I install AMD catalyst in Ubuntu 17.04, or check whether correct drivers are already installed for my AMD GPU?

Tags: radeon, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

I just installed Ubuntu 17.04 on an amd64 laptop with a Radeon graphics card. Although everything works fine and there are no problems related to graphics, I can't locate AMD Catalyst software. I can't figure out whether or not correct AMD graphics driver is installed or not.

How can I do that?

I am using Ubuntu for the first time.

Comment: There is no Catalist software for 17.04.

Comment: that catalyst control panel thing are available only in windows, thus ubuntu dropped support for amd gpus since 16.04. What you are using maybe is the open source driver wich are fine for minimal things... you can see the list of graphical drivers just typing `ubuntu-drivers devices` command